# current_path() inside theme_menu_link returns previous path

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have posted the question at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/111080/current-path-inside-theme-menu-link-returns-previous-path but didn't get much response. Since this is more programming related, I would like to try it here.

I am trying to hide/show menu links based on my current page.  I have added the following snippet into my **template.php** file under **mytheme** folder.

```
/**
* Implements theme_menu_link().
*/
function mytheme_menu_link(array $variables) {
   $path = current_path();
   debug($path);
   //Do things based on $path

}
```

I have observed a very strange output of $path value. I will try to illustrator will a table

```
Time        |    Url          |   displayed $path value
   1        |    mysite/link1 |   none
   2        |    mysite/link2 |   link1
   3        |    mysite/link3 |   link2
```

It looks like the "current_path()" function call inside my mytheme_menu_link always returns the **previous path**. I have spent a full day googling and didn't see any case that is similar to mine.

Can someone tell me what is the possible cause and how I can avoid it?

Thanks!

PS: I have another call for current_path() inside **mymodule_block_list_alter** function and that one works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Strange. This should work as expected. Is $_GET ['q'] modified somewhere in your code? Try from a fresh Drupal installation to implement the theming function.
Without the full code it is hard to help on this one.